# Excluding results over a period

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an issue comparing data over time.
I would like to exclude data that was existing in the last period but i am missing something.
I want to retrieve only new ref which not existing during the previous period. (this query is part of bigger query thats why you will fond won / lost in my test query)

An other thing i don't understand is why i got this error with production data ?

> SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

```
     CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE "TMP_TEST" (
    "Period"   TIMESTAMP,
    "Country"  VARCHAR,
    "Ref"      VARCHAR,
    "Name"     VARCHAR,
    "Tag"      VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO "TMP_TEST" 
VALUES 
('01/01/2020','US','WZ32  ','WKDM2     ','123'),
('01/01/2020','US','PZ56  ','2GFSDG37  ','456'),
('01/02/2020','US','OD59  ','ORD56     ','123'),
('01/03/2020','US','OD59  ','ORD56     ','123'),
('01/03/2020','US','OD59  ','ORD56     ','456'),
('01/03/2020','US','NULL  ','24GFDSGF2 ','123'),
('01/03/2020','US','RL04  ','24GSFD1   ','123'),
('01/04/2020','US','RL04  ','24GSFD1   ','123');

SELECT * from "TMP_TEST"

SELECT A."Ref",A."Period",A."Name",A."Country",A."Tag", 1 AS "Won",0 AS "Lost"
FROM "TMP_TEST" A
WHERE A."Ref" NOT IN (SELECT B."Ref" FROM "TMP_TEST" B WHERE B."Period" = DATEADD(MONTH, -1,A."Period"))
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
```

Wanted result :

| Period | Country | Ref | Name | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2020 | US | WZ32 | WKDM2 | 123 |
| 01/01/2020 | US | PZ56 | 2GFSDG37 | 456 |
| 01/02/2020 | US | OD59 | ORD56 | 123 |
| 01/03/2020 | US | OD59 | ORD56 | 456 |
| 01/03/2020 | US | NULL | 24GFDSGF2 | 123 |
| 01/03/2020 | US | RL04 | 24GSFD1 | 123 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the sample data provided, have got this as a working solution :

```
SELECT A."Ref",A."Period",A."Name",A."Country",A."Tag", 1 AS "Won",0 AS "Lost"
FROM "TMP_TEST" A
WHERE A."Ref" NOT IN (SELECT B."Ref" FROM "TMP_TEST" B WHERE B."Period" = DATEADD(DAY, -1,A."Period"))
 OR A."Tag" NOT IN (SELECT B."Tag" FROM "TMP_TEST" B WHERE B."Period" = DATEADD(Day, -1,A."Period"))                    
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5;
```

The reason why DATEADD function is changed from month to day is because Snowflake by default reads the data as MM/DD/YYYYY.
So, when using MONTH as the parameter, all the values would be same as the input tables hence there is no exclusion possible.